# Как получить фото пользователя Django

Tags: django

Есть следующая структура - 2 приложения: *account* и *question*. В приложении *account* создается пользователь и добавляется ему фотография. В приложении *question* пользователь может создавать вопросы.

Файл **models.py** приложения **account**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='users/',
                            blank=True,
                            processors=[ResizeToFill(300, 300)],
                            format = 'JPEG',
                            options={'quality': 100})
```

Файл **models.py** приложения **question**

```
class Question(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_question', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    ...
```

При добавлении вопроса пользователя на сайт мне нужно отобразить информацию о вопросе через модель Question. Вся информация отображается, только не знаю как обратиться к полю photo. Помогите разобраться с этой задачей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="{{ some_question.author.profle.photo.url }}">
```

Comment: Отлично, всё работает. Спасибо Вам